# How can I share an existing AMI to someone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I followed the guide [Sharing an AMI with specific AWS accounts - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html), and in my AMI portion, I can see the permission.

However, the one I've shared doesn't get any notification and cannot find the AMI. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't think they get a notification. It simply allows them to access the AMI. Were they using the same Region as the one where the AMI was created? (AMIs are specific to a region.)

Comment: Make sure the account number is correct. Check the region you shared the AMI. If you shared the AMI from `ap-south-1`, you have to look at the AMI in the same region on the other account.